# Compute sum of even powers of x

Tags: c++

I am to compute recurrently (not necessarily recursively) the y, where
$$y = {x}^{2n} + {x}^{2(n-1)} + ... + {x}^{4} + {x}^{2} + x$$

Here is what I am doing:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double polynom(unsigned, double);

int main(void)
{
    cout << polynom(2, 3) << endl;
    return 0;
}

double polynom(unsigned n, double x)
{
    double currentAdd(x);
    double res(0);
    while (n)
    {
        res += currentAdd;
        currentAdd *= currentAdd;
        --n;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Is it possible to do it better?

Comment: What do you mean by "recurrent"? The only association that comes to my mind is recursion.

Comment: Also, better in what aspect? Performance? Code clarity? Algorithm?

Comment: Was it an accident that you missed `x^3`?

Comment: Also why not have `x^0` in there?

Comment: Are you doing "even powers of x" or "2**n powers of x"? Your loop seems to be computing the latter. (x^4 times x^4 is x^8, not x^6)

Comment: Wait, why do you compute x? x is x^1 which is odd?

Comment: Furthermore: 3 + 3^2 + 3^4 + 3^6 = 822, your program outputs 6654

Comment: @BenSteffan, it means that every next element of the sequence can be represented by using a previous one.

Comment: @BenSteffan, in every possible way.

Comment: @LokiAstari, no it was not.

Comment: @LokiAstari, because my task is such.

Comment: @AustinHastings, yeah. You are right, the loop is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Why is _x_ (i.e. _x¹_) included, but no other odd power of _x_?  Is there something special about 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Don't do this:

```
using namespace std;
```

See: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065)

Its a bad habits you should not get into doing (even for small programs). Bad habits bite you in the butt when you get to larger projects and forget to stop doing them.

### Comments

There are a couple of things I would do differently. But I can't say you are doing them wrong.

#### I prefer not to use `unsigned` for numeric values.

```
double polynom(unsigned, double);
```

There is no way to check that what was passed was not negative. I can easily call this with:

```
polynom(-1, 2); // Compiler is happy to convert that -1 to a very large 
                // positive number without an y errors. On the reciving
                // side you can not tell if it was an error.
```

There are very few times when you need the extra bit for larger positive numbers. Any time I have come across this type of case I have just used a larger integer type (not swapped to the unsigned version).

Unsigned values should be reserved for bit masks in user code.

#### Don't use return in main.

```
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't put a return at the end of `main()` then the compiler will automatically plant code to `return 0`. So it is not technically needed.

Additionally not using the `return 0` is a way to indicate that your application can never fail. Note: `return 0` indicates a success to the OS and the compiler is planting it by default to indicate successful termination.

So when I see a `return 0` at the end of `main()` I also start to scan the rest of `main()` to see if there are any other returns (with non zero value) that will indicate the error conditions of the application.

#### Initialization

This is fine.

```
    double currentAdd(x);
    double res(0);
```

But personally I think the `=` sign provides more context.

```
    double currentAdd = x;
    double res        = 0;
```

#### Prefer `for()` over `while()`

This is so 50/50. Its just that `for()` loops can be slightly more compact.

```
    while (n)
    {
        --n;
    }
    // over
    for(;n; --n)
    {
    }
```

Would not worry too much about it though.

Comment: Hmmm... `;n;` Looks kind of funny... But +1 for the `unsigined` comment I see this happen all the time. (Well alternatively, don't check `unsigned` stuff).

Comment: What if `n` is checked for negatives before passing it into the function? In the past, I've used `unsigned` in places where negative values shouldn't be used anyway. They simply didn't exist in that environment and user input was not taken. If you make a number `unsigned`, at least it can't accidentally be negative either (in case of overflow, for example). Do I conclude correctly from your post signed integers should be preferred anyway (unless the exception of bit masks mentioned)?

Comment: @Mast. It can't be accidentally negative and you only have positive numbers. Then using signed values does not hurt you (and you can validate the input if things go wrong). BUT using unsigned you can  not validate if things happened accidentally (and with c++ auto conversions there are lots of opportunities for accidents). The was a panel talk about this at cppcon because `std::size_t` is unsigned. The general consensus is that it was a mistake (but its too late now and we are stuck with it).

Comment: @Mast Personally I would always use signed values for numbers. BUT I don't see it as that incorrect to use unsigned (I just think it is safer to use signed values).

Comment: You are saying that it is a bad idea to use `unsigned` since the compiler won\`t tell you if you pass a negative number. But will it tell you that if you pass a negative number by using `int`?

Comment: Why do you think that initializing with an equal sign is a good idea? It seems to be a lot more clear to use parentheses to show the initialization.

Comment: @trafalgarLaww: Yes. You will be able to detect if a negative singed number is passed to a signed parameter. It will be negative so you can detect it.

Comment: @trafalgarLaww It seems to be a lot more clear to use equal to show initialization. Perspective on that point is totally on the reader. That is also why it is in the section `But I can't say you are doing them wrong.`

Comment: @trafalgarLaww: If you are going to use the '()' rather than `=` then common convention (after c++11) is to use '{}` rather than '()'.  `double currentAdd{x};`. This was an addition to the labguage to try an have a single common initialization form that always worked. The '()' don't work for zero parameters because of the `Most vexing parse` issue.

Comment: Good compilers will warn you when there's an implicit conversion between types of different signedness.  Of course, many "good" compilers cease to be "good" if you don't pass the right arguments to them...

Comment: @TobySpeight Or somebody else uses pragmas in the code to disable certain warnings (like the common warning cause in `for` loops that use size() and an int loop counter). Have gone into a more than one team and had to add a pre-commit check to prevent that pragma being added to the code (again).